# If a user uploads copyrighted material to my site but for personal use is it legal?

Tags: copyright, legal, cloud

I am creating a personal cloud service, each account is only for use by the owner.
You can upload any file and view / play it in the browser, e.g. documents, music and videos.

Now obviously someone's going to upload their music library, which is fine by me, but is it breaching copyright?

The only person who has access to the material would be the account owner, the material is not publicly accessible. So is it legal for someone to upload their iTunes library onto my servers?

Would it be the same for their films?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several services launched by big companies that allow users to upload their music and movies for personal use. Notably, there is [Amazon Cloud Drive](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000828861).

The legality of Amazon's offering is in dispute.  [Amazon says](http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/03/amazon-on-cloud-player-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-licenses/): "Cloud Player is an application that lets customers manage and play their own music. It's like any number of existing media management applications. We do not need a license to make Cloud Player available."

The [music industry says that Amazon needs licences to launch such a service](http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/03/music-industry-will-force-licenses-on-amazon-cloud-playeror-else/)

Movies have additional legal issues since they are typically encrypted on DVDs.  [Circumventing DVD encryption is illegal under the DMCA, even for personal use](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2009/05/legalize-personal-use-dvd-copying/).